# Where does pip install packages with a virtual environment?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

**Situation:** I have created a virtual environment and use an explicit path to run `pip` (without sourcing `activate`). Does it install packages in the global `dist-packages` or does it install them in the virtual environment's `site-packages`.

**Details:**
As [Where does pip install its packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29980798/where-does-pip-install-its-packages) explains, pip installs packages in `<virtualenv_name>/lib/<python_ver>/site-packages` when used with a virtual environment. From my experience, this is true when I activate the virtualenv. I have an existing bash script that paths directly to the `pip` executable without activating the virtualenv. Does this still install packages in the virtualenv's site-packages? Or does it install them in `/local/lib/<python-version>/dist-packages`?

Note: I'm on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Under *ix, check the first line of the script you're calling (i.e. `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/pip`) to understand which Python - and therefore which package installation targets - it's referencing.

Comment: Virtualenv "activation" simply modifies the `PATH` variable so the right executable is prepended (it actually does more than that, but it's not relevant here). `source env/bin/activate && pip install` is thus the same as invoking `env/bin/pip install` directly.

Comment: @blubberdiblub What do you mean by "*ix"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Linux, Unix, MacOS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This very much depends on *which* version (not in the semantic version sense, but of the having-multiple-"versions" of pip installed when you create a venv) of pip your script is using, as well as its configuration (including possibly your environment).

Assuming your script has a line like

```
/some/path/to/pip install <some package>
```

and assuming that that pip has installed at least one package, you can use

```
/some/path/to/pip show <that package>
```

and it'll give you output that looks like:

```
$ pip show numpy
Name: numpy
Version: 1.14.5
Summary: NumPy: array processing for numbers, strings, records, and objects.
Home-page: http://www.numpy.org
Author: Travis E. Oliphant et al.
Author-email: None
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
Requires:
```

The location line second to last should help answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

When you're using an explicit path to the Python executable associated with the venv, e.g. `.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install ...`, then pip will install to the virtual environment's site e.g. `.venv/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages`. Whether the venv is activated or not is irrelevant in this case.

However, if you use a command which will be resolved in $PATH such as `pip`, instead of the unambiguous command `path/to/python -m pip`, then things can get complicated.

1. The executable file that a bare command such as `pip` references on the filesystem depends on $PATH.  Look in `which pip` for the right one (`type pip` if someone was really evil and made a shell alias for it). Look in `which -a pip` to see what other ones are hanging around that the first one might be shadowing. Note that some shells cache the command-to-file mapping, and sometimes screw up their cache invalidation (try `hash -r` if you're seeing weird behaviour and you think your shell has a messed up cache).
2. A command such as `./pip` or `.venv/bin/pip` will *not* search through $PATH. That's because it has a slash in it.
3. OK, so you've found your *file* `pip`, it's an executable script. The first line of this file, called the *shebang*, tells you which interpreter is associated to that pip script. Look in `head -1 .venv/bin/pip`. If pip was installed into a venv then this will always match the venv's Python, assuming you didn't edit it manually, because the installer itself writes this shebang out (fun fact: even if you put a different one directly in your source code, the installer rewrote it!).
4. `pip install` will put the files where the associated interpreter's sysconfig says. Point 1 tells you exactly what "pip" means and Point 2 showed you exactly what "associated interpreter" means. The sysconfig locations are platform dependent. Find out where by running `path/to/python -m sysconfig | grep "Paths:" --after 10` and look for the "purelib" path.
5. There is unfortunately an extra complication for Ubuntu users! This distribution is a Debian derivative, so they have a [patched distutils installation](https://salsa.debian.org/cpython-team/python3/-/blob/master/debian/patches/distutils-install-layout.diff) due to [Debian policies on Python packaging](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/index.html#module-path). TL;DR: on Ubuntu the system site dir will be named `dist-packages` instead of `site-packages` as sysconfig reports.

There is nothing magical about "activating" a venv, it just sets env vars such as $PATH.  If you understand how 1-3 works, you understand how activating a venv works.

So now you should be able to reason the answer without guessing: using a path like `.venv/bin/pip` versus activating a venv (which changes $PATH, which changes what `pip` means, resulting to the same `.venv/bin/pip`) makes no difference.

***Addendum:*** *Why do people have so much trouble with pip installations?*

[Bad hygiene.](https://xkcd.com/1987/) I think they screwed up their systems by messing with `sys.path` in some way or another (appending to it in startup scripts, user site, sitecustomize.py, setting `PYTHONPATH` env var in .bashrc, installing some crappy package that mutated it, following some crappy guide that had a `sudo pip install`... the possibilities are endless!)

Look at the `pip` "script", it's just a console entry-point written out by setuptools.  This script is created from a template at install time.  You won't actually find this file anywhere in pip's source, because *it doesn't exist there*.

```
#!/path/to/.venv/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal.main import main  # <--- look at this import statement! 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

The first thing the executable script does is try to import its private APIs from a `pip` *module*, and where that `from pip` module import gets resolved depends on `sys.path`. First match wins. When pip appears randomly broken, you should always ask yourself "is this import statement still finding the same `pip/__init__.py` file which was written out by the installer when it created the script?"

If it's not, or the shebang looks wrong, just delete it and reinstall pip.