# cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

On my mac, pip3 exists in /usr/bin. When I try to install any package using pip3, it is failing. Even simple 'pip3' also failing with below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands import (
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder
ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip._internal.index' (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/index/__init__.py)
```

I tried to remove /usr/bin/pip3. But it is saying operation is not permitted. I am unable to remove pip3. Can any one please let me know how to fix this issue.

**Note: I went through some stack overflow questions related to this. Most of the answers suggested to uninstall and install pip3. But I am unable to remove pip3.**

Comment: This happens when another version of pip got installed/upgraded, but the old pip console script entry point, still on $PATH, for some reason did not get removed or replaced (usually because the installer did not have write permission).  I demonstrate how to fix such a broken pip installation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665743/674039).

Comment: I am able to see only one occurrence of pip3 on my mac which is in /usr/bin.